# Create a List of Pandas DataFrames after creating the Data Frames using a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a machine that dumps rubbish into various dumpsters and for each full cycle I have created a pandas dataframe of the time stamp that rubbish is dumped into each dumpster. I need to create a list of all the created `Dataframes`. I have done it manually knowing how many dataframes I have already but it is not dynamic.

I have tried `array[j] = ('DumpingTime_' + str(j))` which works and fills the array with strings of the names for each of the Dataframes but I need it to fill the array up with the actual data frames if you get me? Please see the code section for entire code.

So like this except this is not dynamic and would have to go into the code and change it every time the number of cycles changes `array = [DumpingTime_0,DumpingTime_1,DumpingTime_2)`

```
index = ['Dump_1','Dump_2','Dump_3']
columns = ['Dumpster_1','Dumpster_2','Dumpster_3','Dumpster_4','Dumpster_5','Dumpster_6']
for j in range(0,Number_of_Complete_Cycles+1,1):
    globals()["DumpingTime_" + str(j)] = pd.DataFrame(data=First_Cycle_Time_arr[0:,0:],index=index,columns=columns).astype(int) + (j)*Complete_Cycle_Time
    name_array[j] = ('DumpingTime_' + str(j))
```

Comment: if I try this -   name_array[j] = ["DumpingTime_" + str(j)]  I get an error that I can't convert string to float: 'DumpingTime_0'. But again this looks like its adding the name rather than the actual data frame to the array

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're asking. What is your expected output/goal?